# How to limit simultaneous run od AWS CodePipeline to 1?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

How can I "force" AWS CodePipeline to run only once at same time, and after it finish this run (with green or red) it will progress next run?
Would like to stop situation like on the picture:
[image]

Comment: Why? Doesn't this hint at the fact that your stages are not properly designed / the two shown stages should be merged into one stage!?

Comment: If you could take a look two different commits ids are in the picture. I wont change this setup. Would like to know what are possibilities to reduce the runs to just one (one commit from source to last stage, either success or failure next run, etc...) I saw some theory about DynamoDB and through a conditional put in a DynamoDB table, but have no clue how this could be done

Comment: *"I wont change this setup"* - then you are out of luck and won't get any help (from me).

Comment: Sure, no problem :) I just cant since it is not mine :) This one is in different project so do not have permissions. I just would like to know how to avoid this :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stages redesign did the trick - thx @luk2302 ;D.

More info (which truly helped) at AWS docs - [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/concepts-how-it-works.html)